# SSL Connection error API Linkedin when we try to get accessToken

Tags: linkedin-api

Since last week, I got a curl error **'SSL Connection error'** from LinkedIn API when I try to get an accessToken. This remain only in one server and domain. I don't get this error from other domains.

Do you have insights on it ? It was working correctly before, we have valid ssl certificates so we stuck a little on it.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, try to set

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```